# How to dynamically iterate an index based on a repeating series in one column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that's a set of data recordings that are each 400 channels long, with each channel number listed under the channel column of my dataframe, like so,

```
index   channel input   Baseline
0       0       2129    2129
1       1       2128    2129            
2       2       2129    2129       
3       3       2129    2129        
4       4       2129    2129       
5       5       2129    2129       

...

396     396     2128    2127    
397     397     2128    2127    
398     398     2127    2127    
399     399     2127    2127    
400     0       2130    2128    
401     1       2130    2128    
402     2       2131    2128    

...
```

and so on

What I am trying to do is set the index so each series of 400 channels is individually indexed like this,

```
index   channel input   Baseline
0       0       2129    2129
        1       2128    2129            
        2       2129    2129       
        3       2129    2129        
        4       2129    2129       
        5       2129    2129       

...

        396     2128    2127    
        397     2128    2127    
        398     2127    2127    
        399     2127    2127    
1       0       2130    2128    
        1       2130    2128    
        2       2131    2128    

...
```

Apologies if this is something that's blindingly obvious but I am a bit of a beginner at working with python and code in general

edit: thanks for the help! Surprising that the groupby function is bugged in python3

Comment: Have a look at the `pandas` multi-index [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html). Your learning process is going to be more successful if you try to solve these issues yourself. Try to write some code that does what you want, and if results do not make sense then the community will be happy to help.

Comment: I had a look at that before asking the question but couldn't see anything that quite helped with the issue I'm trying to resolve, which might be because I'm still too new to python.

My problem is partially due to the size of these files. The smallest goes up to an index of almost 12 million so I can't personally assign an index to each group of 400 individually like appears to be the process in the multi-index docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counting with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(df.groupby('channel').cumcount())
print (df)
   channel  input  Baseline
0        0   2129      2129
0        1   2128      2129
0        2   2129      2129
0        3   2129      2129
0        4   2129      2129
0        5   2129      2129
0      396   2128      2127
0      397   2128      2127
0      398   2127      2127
0      399   2127      2127
1        0   2130      2128
1        1   2130      2128
1        2   2131      2128
```

Or maybe if need [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html):

```
df = df.set_index([df.groupby('channel').cumcount(), 'channel'])
print (df)
           input  Baseline
  channel                 
0 0         2129      2129
  1         2128      2129
  2         2129      2129
  3         2129      2129
  4         2129      2129
  5         2129      2129
  396       2128      2127
  397       2128      2127
  398       2127      2127
  399       2127      2127
1 0         2130      2128
  1         2130      2128
  2         2131      2128
```

---

Or create new column first:

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby('channel').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['idx', 'channel'])
print (df)
             input  Baseline
idx channel                 
0   0         2129      2129
    1         2128      2129
    2         2129      2129
    3         2129      2129
    4         2129      2129
    5         2129      2129
    396       2128      2127
    397       2128      2127
    398       2127      2127
    399       2127      2127
1   0         2130      2128
    1         2130      2128
    2         2131      2128
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response!

Unfortunately I get the following error when I try that,

TypeError: unorderable types: numpy.ndarray() < str()

Comment: In each case I'm getting the same error. I'll dig into the data and see if there's anything unexpected there, as far as I know everything in that column should be ints

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you can try upgrade pandas, last version is `0.20.2`.

Comment: Got your solutions working. Did a little digging into the error and it seems that for some reason groupby has issues in python3.

I switched to using python2 and all of your suggestions worked.

Thanks! You've been a great help :)

I've tried giving you an upvote but it seems I need a rank over 15 to do so publicly :S